# How to find out the time in seconds since log on?

Tags: macos, cocoa, unix

I like to know how much time in second has elapsed since the user logged on. (`TickCount` is not good because that is from system start)

I know I can use `last` or `who` to get the timestamp but what I am looking for a simple but robust solution.
I would use it in Cocoa but a unix command is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I used getlastlogx(), thanks for Rob Napier for pointing me to the right direction (+1).

this is I came up with:

```
    struct lastlogx *lastLogin;
    uid_t myuid = getuid();
    lastLogin = getlastlogx(myuid,nil);
    NSDate *dateAtLogon = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:lastLogin->ll_tv.tv_sec];
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval timeSinceLogin = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:dateAtLogon];
    NSLog(@"%1.1f seconds since logon",timeSinceLogin);
```

Answer (score 3):

See the [utmpx(5)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/utmpx.5.html) interface, specifically [endutxent(3)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/endutxent.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/endutxent). It's the programmatic interface to what you're looking at from `who` and `last`.

Comment: If I use getlastlogx() from a non-admin account it generates an exception and crashes because lastlogin is nill. I did a workaround but it would be nice to know how to get the information from a non-previliged account.